# Por que meu Bean não está recebendo o submit do formulário?

Tags: jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2

Por que meu Bean não está reconhecendo o atributo de um selectOneMenu simples:
Eu criei no meu Bean o atributo `private Long areaprevencaoId`. 
Este atributo está associado ao um `<p:selectOneMenu>`

xhtml

```
   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.areaPrevencaoId}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.listaAreaPrevencaoSelect}"></f:selectItems>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <p:commandButton action="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.incluirArea}" value="Incluir" 
        process="@this" update="panel-grid-equipe" immediate="true" />
```

Meu Bean que usa o atributo:

```
    public void incluirArea() {
    if (areaPrevencaoId == null) {
        messages.error("Selecione uma Equipe");
    } else {
        usuarioPrevencao.setUsuarioId(usuario.getId());
        usuarioPrevencao.setAreaprevencaoId(areaPrevencaoId);
        try {
            usuarioPrevencaoRepository.salvar(usuarioPrevencao);
            //this.listaUsuarioPrevencao = usuarioPrevencaoRepository.todosIdUsuario(usuario.getId());
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            messages.error("Erro ao gravar os dados da Equipe do Usuário");
        }
    }
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(Arrays.asList("msg-area-prevencao","painel-equipe"));
}
```

Comment: Minha sugestão é que faça o `process` do formulário em vez do `CommandButton`, senão nenhum dos componentes do `form` vão passar pelo ciclo de vida jsf e assim atualizar o seu modelo (`Bean`).

Comment: Wakin fiz o ajuste, mas ainda está indo nulo.

Comment: Colocasse `@form` no atributo `process`?

Comment: Wakin, você estava certo. No xhtml estava tudo dentro de um único form. Separei e fiz o `process="@form"` e funcionou. Valeu!

Comment: vou colocar como resposta para que os demais possam encontrar a solução do problema caso seja a mesma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso, você deve trocar o `process="@this"` para `process="@form"` pois assim todo o formulário será processado ao invés de apenas o botão.

Com o formulário sendo processado, todos os componentes dentro do mesmo serão e o `selectOneMenu` irá atualizar o modelo, o atributo do seu `Bean`, com o valor selecionado.

Answer (score 1):

Levando em consideração que você está utilizando o framework [`Primefaces`](http://www.primefaces.org/), sugiro também que estude o seguinte tópico: [`Ajax Framework - PFS`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/selector.xhtml).

É uma implementação que permite o processamento (**process**) e atualização (**update**) de componentes utilizando a [`API de seletores`](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) utilizada pelo [`JQuery`](http://jquery.com/).

Pode não ser o seu caso específico, mas existem situações onde seu formulário possui uma grande quantidade de componentes, e o envio de todos eles vai acabar apenas por impactar na performance da sua aplicação.

O recomendado é que você envie e/ou atualize apenas os elementos necessários.

Comment: Romulo obrigado pela dica. Abraços